Opensearch Camel component (4.8.1), "indexRequestBuilder" is null issue
I'm working on a proof of concept to connect Apache Camel with OpenSearch, but I'm running into a consistent issue. Here's the setup and the problem I'm encountering:
Setup:

Opensearch version: 2.17.0
Camel version: 4.8.1
camel-opensearch: 4.8.1

Problem Description:
I'm trying to set up a route in Apache Camel to connect to an OpenSearch instance, but I'm getting always the following error:
camel                  | [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 4.8.1 (camel-1) is starting
camel                  | [main] INFO org.apache.camel.component.opensearch.OpensearchProducer - Connecting to the OpenSearch cluster: opensearch
camel                  | [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Routes startup (total:1)
camel                  | [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext -     Started route1 (direct://index)
camel                  | [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 4.8.1 (camel-1) started in 408ms (build:0ms init:0ms start:408ms)
**camel                  | [main] INFO route1 - Error indexing document in OpenSearch: Cannot invoke "org.opensearch.client.opensearch.core.IndexRequest$Builder.build()" because "indexRequestBuilder" is null**
camel                  | Response from OpenSearch: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@5a7005dl

Reproduction Steps:

Stack OpenSearch-Camel: I have a running instance of OpenSearch and Camel started via Docker:

version: "3.8"

volumes:
  opensearch-data:

services:
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.17.0
    container_name: opensearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster # Name the cluster
      - node.name=opensearch # Name the node that will run in this container
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch # Node to look for when discovering the cluster
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch # Node eligible to serve as cluster manager
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # Disable JVM heap memory swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # Set min and max JVM heap sizes to at least 50% of system RAM
      - "DISABLE_INSTALL_DEMO_CONFIG=true" # Prevents execution of bundled demo script which installs demo certificates and security configurations to OpenSearch
      - "DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true" # Disables Security plugin
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1 # Set memlock to unlimited (no soft or hard limit)
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # Maximum number of open files for the opensearch user - set to at least 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data:/usr/share/opensearch/data # Creates volume and mounts it to the container
    ports:
      - 9200:9200 # REST API
      - 9600:9600 # Performance Analyzer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:9200/ || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 100

  opensearch-dashboards:
      image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest
      depends_on:
        opensearch:
          condition: service_healthy # Waits for the "opensearch" service to be healthy
      container_name: opensearch-dashboards
      ports:
        - 5601:5601 # Map host port 5601 to container port 5601
      environment:
        - 'OPENSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://opensearch:9200"]'
        - "DISABLE_SECURITY_DASHBOARDS_PLUGIN=true" # disables security dashboards plugin in OpenSearch Dashboards

  camel:
    build:
      context: ./camel-connector  # Directorio donde está el Dockerfile para Camel Quarkus
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: camel
    depends_on:
      opensearch:
          condition: service_healthy  # Espera a que el servicio "opensearch" esté saludable




Camel configuration


Pom.xml


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependencia para Apache Camel Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel OpenSearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-opensearch</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-main</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
                  

        <!-- SLF4J Simple Logging Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.12</version> 
      </dependency>        
    </dependencies>



Application.java

package com.example;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.component.opensearch.OpensearchComponent;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

        OpensearchComponent opensearchComponent = new OpensearchComponent();
        opensearchComponent.setHostAddresses("opensearch:9200");
        

        camelContext.addComponent("opensearch", opensearchComponent);


        // Add the route to Camel context
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RandomDataToOpenSearchRoute());
        camelContext.start();

        // Prepare the document content as a Map
        Map<String, String> document = new HashMap<>();
        document.put("content", "This is a test document for OpenSearch indexing55555.");

        // Send the document to the route and retrieve the response
        ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        String response = template.requestBody("direct:index", document, String.class);

        System.out.println("Response from OpenSearch: " + response);

        // Keep the application running briefly to allow processing
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // Stop the Camel context
        camelContext.stop();
    }
}

RandomDataToOpenSearchRoute.java
package com.example;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RandomDataToOpenSearchRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RandomDataToOpenSearchRoute.class);
    private static final String INDEX_NAME = "my-index";

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        onException(Exception.class)
            .log("Error indexing document in OpenSearch: ${exception.message}")
            .handled(true);

        from("direct:index")
            .process(exchange -> {
                // Set document content as JSON
                Map<String, Object> document = exchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class);
                if (document == null) {
                    document = new HashMap<>();
                    document.put("content", "This is a test document for OpenSearch indexing.");
                }
                exchange.getIn().setBody(document);
            })
            // This commented part works
            // .marshal().json()  // Convert the document to JSON
            // .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            // .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            // .to("http://opensearch:9200/" + INDEX_NAME + "/_doc")
            .to("opensearch://opensearch?operation=Index&indexName=" + INDEX_NAME)
            .log("Document indexed successfully.");
    }
}

What I've Tried:

Verified that OpenSearch is running and accessible at http://localhost:9200 using curl and custom scripts
Confirmed that there are no firewall nor security issues blocking the connection.
Checked the Camel logs for more details.
Used several versions of components, Opensearch, Camel, Maven etc.
Camel opensearchComponent configurations.
Opensearch configuration (you need to create via Opensearch dashboard for example the index to be use),
Followed example in https://camel.apache.org/components/4.8.x/opensearch-component.html

Expected Behavior:
I expect the Camel route to send a query to OpenSearch like the commented part but using the Camel opensearch Component
Actual Behavior:
The route fails to connect, and I receive camel                  | [main] INFO route1 - Error indexing document in OpenSearch: Cannot invoke "org.opensearch.client.opensearch.core.IndexRequest$Builder.build()" because "indexRequestBuilder" is null No matter the mapping, nor data etc. Comment section RandomDataToOpenSearchRoute works fine.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
